# alt text not showing when hovering over image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have the following code:

```
<td><%= link_to(image_tag("delete.gif", :size => "16x16", :alt => "Delete Entry"), phone, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote=>true, :class=>'delete_phone') %></td>
```

in my view. Now, it all works fine and does what I need it to, but when I hover over the icon, well, it doesn't show me any text. I've tried in Firefox and Chrome.

Has anyone else come across the same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: When you view the HTML source in your web browser, is the ALT tag present? If so, you might consider using the title attribute as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#protip - it can be a painful (and very un-DRY) exercise to add `title`s for all your images.  To make this a lot less painful all my apps ship with this JS (require [jquery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$(function() {
  $('img').each( function() {
    var o = $(this);
    if( ! o.attr('title') && o.attr('alt') ) o.attr('title', o.attr('alt') );
  });
});
```

This sets the `title` of any `img` without a `title` to the value of it's `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 12):

Use title, not alt, and your problems will be solved! Alt is for accessibility - it means "alternate". Title is what you'd use for a tooltip.

Answer (score 7):

On hover image `title` text is shown in tooltip.

`Alt` text is for users with disabled images (or slow connection) and search engines

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea about Ruby, but you need to use the title attribute in HTML to get the rollover text appearing in most browsers.. Does that help at all?

eg

```
<img title="hello thar" src="hellothar.gif" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use title option to display text in rails 3.

```
<%= image_tag 'Profile.png',:title => 'Profile'  %>
```

When mouse hover over the **Profile.png**, it will show the text **Profile**.