# why img alt not working in ionic?

Tags: image, alt

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
        <a menu-close href="#/app/account" class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="{{user.detail.avatarUrl}}" on-error-src="img/avatar.jpg">
            <h2>{{user.detail.nickname}}</h2>
            <p>{{user.attributes.username}}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/login">
            登陆
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-image">
            <img alt="个人信息" src="img/wudics.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item item-image">
            <p>扫描二维码下载APP版</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I have set the **alt** tag inside **img** tag, but this is not working. I want to implement that it can show a tip when my mouse **hover** on the image.

how to do that? please help.

Comment: Could be duplicate of [alt text not showing when hovering over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814595/alt-text-not-showing-when-hovering-over-image)

Comment: thanks man, you are so pro. are you csgo player?

Comment: np. I am glad the link was helpful. Unfortunately, I am not a csgo player :) enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know alt tag was not intended to be used in this way being alternative text if the image can not be displayed or if read using text to speech software for blind people.

Try the title attribute for additional information about the image.

example title="your text"

Not sure why it's not displaying though.